# Breaking image down into the fixed-size tiles

Tags: python, image

[Ported this question from Superuser, as it may be too comp-sciish]

Suppose you have a high-res, `x1` by `y1` image (maybe 40000x20000), and you want to display it on an embedded system's screen of `x2` by `x2` (maybe 800x600), where scaling/magnifying isn't supposed. You may resize it down to the target resolution, but you want to preserve the tiny details. So you want to let it show `x2` by `y2`, `n` tiles of the original image.

[This solution](https://superuser.com/questions/35832/split-a-image-into-tiles) shows how to divide into some arbitrary `n` tiles, but I actually seek for dividing into dynamic amount of tiles, where

```
n = max(math.ceil(x1/x2), math.ceil(y1/y2))
```

Notice here, that `x1/x2` isn't necessarily equal to `y1/y2`, as well as their results aren't necessarily integer. So before dividing into tiles, we would need to add some padding, which, let's say, has to be either/both at the right-hard side and at the bottom

Can anyone suggest some software/script capable of this? Perhaps so it could easily be automated. I believe ImageMagick may work, though I'm not too sure.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/) for that. Check their [-crop](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#crop) option which allows to specify an offset and a size, then you can use that to crop away each of the tiles you need.

For example use this command:

```
magick original.png -crop 330x330+400+220 result.png
```

To turn this image:

[image]

Into this one:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This would be super easy with Python "Pillow".

From its [doc page](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.crop) for `crop()`:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("hopper.jpg")

# The crop method from the Image module takes four coordinates as input.
# The right can also be represented as (left+width)
# and lower can be represented as (upper+height).
(left, upper, right, lower) = (20, 20, 100, 100)

# Here the image "im" is cropped and assigned to new variable im_crop
im_crop = im.crop((left, upper, right, lower))
```

Just set up a loop in x and a loop in y, carve out chunks of dx by dy.

Answer (score 1):

GDAL's `gdal2tiles` might be what you are looking for: [link](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2tiles.html).

Summary from it's manpage:

> This utility generates a directory with small tiles and metadata, following the OSGeo Tile Map Service Specification. Simple web pages with viewers based on Google Maps, OpenLayers and Leaflet are generated as well - so anybody can comfortably explore your maps on-line and you do not need to install or configure any special software (like MapServer) and the map displays very fast in the web browser. You only need to upload the generated directory onto a web server.

Answer (score 0):

[OP here]

A friend of mine suggested the following solution via ImageMagick

```
"ImageMagick-6.8.0-Q16\convert.exe" "src_path\Source Image.jpg" -crop 70x80 -background White -extent 70x80 -gravity NorthWest "dest_path\Destination Image%d.jpg"
```

70x80 are being `x2 by y2`

Not sure if it works, will give it a try